# Что такое стоимость запроса в SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Что такое стоимость запроса и как ее узнать в `SQLiteStudio (3.2.1)`?

Есть много сайтов, где про нее что-то написано

[Здесь](https://sql-ex.ru/blogs/?/Ne_pora_li_ubrat_stoimost_iz_plana_zaprosa.html) описывается что все неправильно понимают, что такое стоимость. И чем стоимость полезна.

[Здесь](https://www.fors.ru/upload/magazine/07/http_text/russia_mihjeichev_plan_recomendations.html) говорится, как уменьшить стоимость.

А в учебнике `Грофф Дж. Р., Вайнберг П.Н., Оппель Э. Дж. - SQL. Полное руководство - 2015` на 900 с лишним страниц такое понятие вообще ни разе не упоминается.

Comment: *Что такое стоимость запроса* Попытка оценить затраты ресурсов на выполнение запроса "в попугаях".

Comment: Открой план запроса, там ты увидишь все операции которые произошли при выполнении этого запроса. В каждой операции указано в % отношении сколько ресурсов она потребила (100% это выполненный запрос) . Это и есть стоимость.

Comment: @Akina Да, видел, что в 3000 попугаев и более. Только вот вопрос, эти попугаи, это тики системы или что?

Answer (score 0):

Открой план запроса, там ты увидишь все операции которые произошли при выполнении этого запроса. В каждой операции указано в % отношении сколько ресурсов она потребила (100% это выполненный запрос) . Это и есть стоимость.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это стоимости отдельных операций в составе запроса, а не запроса в целом.

Comment: Если запросы идут пакетом, то смысл тот же, только там указывается уже сколько затрачивает запрос по отношению к пакету.

Comment: То есть ты хочешь сказать, что стоимость запрос это проценты?

Comment: Интересно, тогда почему запрос с большей стоимостью в пакете отрабатывает быстрее запроса с меньшей стоимостью?